# Warning: control reaches end of non void function

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, warnings

I'm pretty sure I have the correct return statement so i don't know why it shows this.

/* check table full function */

```
bool check_table_full (char board[][SIZE])
{
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
        if (board[row][col] != '_') {
        return true;
        }
        else {
        return false;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: both your loops will execute exactly once, since the function **always** returns on the first iteration. So your program is equivalent to: `if (board[0][0] != '_') { return true; } else { return false;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, for example:

```
bool check_table_full (char board[][SIZE])
{
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] != '_') {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: would this still follow the code that if board[row][col] != '_', return false and likewise for false

Comment: It depends on the situation. In fact, returning a value every time in a for loop is not a process. You can set a variable of bool type like row and col inside this method, then assign it true or false on the for loop based on the if statement, and finally return the variable of that bool type.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler often can’t understand what seems to be obvious to humans.  You need a default return at the end to convince the compiler.  Or restructure the function so you are not returning in the middle of the function.

Comment: Then how would I restructure in a way that makes sense to the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

This code will work:

```
bool check_table_full (char board[][SIZE])
{
    int row, col;

    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
            if (board[row][col] != '_') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).